# How to pass hml with event bindings as a string into the render() method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to take an HTML string that has `a` tags within it, assign event handlers to them, and render them. Example html:

```
This is a sample blog post with HTML. <a data-id="1">Click here.</a>
```

I can use jQuery to parse this HTML string and insert events (or props, or anything else), like so:

```
This is a sample blog post with HTML. <a data-id="1" ref="myClick" onClick={this.handleClick}>Click here.</a>
```

Now I want to render it:

```
return (
            <div>
                <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: theHtml}}></p>
            </div>
        );
```

But this renders the raw HTML without any React magic. How do I create the HTML/formatting as a string and then render it as normal?

Comment: The string format you're showing uses JSX style syntax which is normally a compile time only syntax. While there is a way to use it a runtime, it wouldn't be efficient or recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no good way to do this.  The best I can think of would be parsing the string into a html ast, and then creating virtual dom from that.  It's not very fast or easy to do.

Other than that, your options are:

- don't have a html string

  - have data which you can generate virtual dom from
  - this is always best, if possible
- use dangerouslySetInnerHTML and attach listeners manually in componentDidMount

  - slow if there's a lot of listeners, and you need to clean them up in componentWillUnmount
- put react event handlers on the wrapper div, and use e.target to see what the target of the event was (i.e. using event bubbling)

Example of the second bullet:

```
componentDidMount: function(){
    var el = this.getDOMNode();
    // add a click listener to the first <a> child
    el.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', this.aClick)
},
componentWillUnmount: function(){
    var el = this.getDOMNode();
    el.querySelector('a').removeEventListener('click', this.aClick)
},
aClick: function(event){ ... }
```

Comment: Would you mind giving or linking examples for "parsing the string into a html ast, and then creating virtual dom from that", and your second bullet point with using componentDidMount?

Comment: I don't have an example of the html ast option, and as I said it's not easy to do.  I added an example of the manual listeners.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! The second or third point seem to work well. The third doesn't require any cleanup and seems relatively harmless, so I may opt for that. Thank you for your time!